# network unlocking a phone quickly

Tags: java, android, adb

I have a lot of network locked phones that I need to network unlock. I have an excel sheet with the imei of every phone and its associated unlock code. Is there a way to quickly get this done. For Samsung phones you can input #7465625*638*# and then it will ask you for the unlock code. Lg phones are done by inputting 2945#*model number# . These are the two main types of brands that I have. Any thoughts and how this can be done? I would really appreciate it. You dont need to write any code. I would just like to know if  its possible and what technology i would need to use.

Comment: Questions about topics other than development or programming, but related to Android, are not on-topic here, but may be on-topic at https://android.stackexchange.com.  Please review [what types of questions are on-topic in that community](//android.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) before posting there to ensure that your question is on-topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using "`adb shell input text <your_string>`" would speed up entering that information (instead of by hand) if these phones have adb enabled.

Comment: This is helpful. I just need to find a way to mass enable adb on all my phones.

Comment: Hypothetically, if you had some way of emulating a USB keyboard, you could likely do most of what you need that way simply by using key events to do everything